# Realizar función que evalue si en una celda de un DataFrame existe un texto en una lista

Tags: python, pandas

Cree un Data Frame para poder realizar una lista de las marcas más vendidas de él siguiente dataset:

[cellphoneslisting.csv](https://github.com/jchemile/varios/blob/master/challenge/cellphoneslisting.csv)

Lo que hice para solucionar el problema fue "Hardcodear" las marcas y en el nuevo DataFrame agruparlo. En definitiva, el corazón de la solución se encuentra acá:

```
df['brand'] = pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Samsung"), "Samsung", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Sansung"), "Samsung", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Galaxy"), "Samsung",
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Samgung"), "Samsung",
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Philco"), "Philco", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Kanji"), "Kanji", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Nokia"), "Nokia", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Lenovo"), "Lenovo", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Xiaomi"), "Xiaomi",
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Energizer"), "Energizer", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Vodafone"), "Vodafone", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Bgh"), "Bgh", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Zte"), "Zte", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Nextel"), "Nextel", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Blu"), "Blu", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Quantum"), "Quantum", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Micromax"), "Micromax",                      
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Cat"), "Cat",                        
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Lava"), "Lava",                     
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Infinix"), "Infinix", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Wiko"), "Wiko", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Tecno"), "Tecno", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Meizu"), "Meizu", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Vivo"), "Vivo", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Asus"), "Asus", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Oneplus"), "Oneplus", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Microsoft"), "Microsoft",                      
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Huawei"), "Huawei",                        
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Sony"), "Sony", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Lg"), "Lg", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Panasonic"), "Panasonic", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Plum"), "Plum", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Yu"), "Yu", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Verykool"), "Verykool", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Blackberry"), "Blackberry", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Alcatel"), "Alcatel",                      
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Apple"), "Iphone", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Iphone"), "Iphone",            
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Htc"), "Htc", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Motorola"), "Motorola", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Moto"), "Motorola",
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Acer"), "Acer", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Google"), "Google", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Honor"), "Honor", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Oppo"), "Oppo", 
              pd.np.where(df.title.str.contains("Realme"), "Realme", "Otros"))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Sin embargo lo que quiero hacer es evaluar si en una celda contiene valores que se dan en una lista, la cuál iría iterando hasta encontrarlo. Pero, por ejemplo cuándo pienso una función que retorne todos los nombres de una lista lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
def listPhoneBrands(list_phones):
    for brand in list_phones:
        return brand
```

La función me devuelve sólo el primero (porque el return termina una función). Entonces: ¿Cómo se realiza el procedimiento en el cuál una función retorna todos los elementos que se le pasan por una lista? y ¿Existe una formá más óptima de evaluar el contenido de un dataDrame que como lo estoy haciendo?

El resto del código lo pueden encontrar en el repositorio de gitHub: [hardcoding_solution](https://github.com/jchemile/varios/blob/master/challenge/hardcoding_solution.ipynb)

En definitiva, busco una solución más escalable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para dar un orden podemos crear un diccionario donde la clave sea la *marca* y el valor una lista de las opciones de textos que se mapean a la *marca*.

```
d = {
    "Samsung": ["Samsung", "Sansung", "Galaxy", "Samgung"],
    "Philco": ["Philco"],
    "Kanji": ["Kanji"],
    "Nokia": ["Nokia"],
    "Motorola": ["Motorola", "Moto"],
    "Realme": ["Realme"],
    "Oppo": ["Oppo"],
    "Honor": ["Honor"],
    "Lenovo": ["Lenovo"],
    "Xiaomi": ["Xiaomi"],
    "Energizer": ["Energizer"], 
    "Vodafone": ["Vodafone"], 
    "Bgh": ["Bgh"], 
    "Zte": ["Zte"], 
    "Nextel": ["Nextel"], 
    "Blu": ["Blu"], 
    "Quantum": ["Quantum"], 
    "Micromax": ["Micromax"],                      
    "Cat": ["Cat"],                        
    "Lava": ["Lava"],                     
    "Infinix": ["Infinix"], 
    "Wiko": ["Wiko"], 
    "Tecno": ["Tecno"], 
    "Meizu": ["Meizu"], 
    "Vivo": ["Vivo"], 
    "Asus": ["Asus"], 
    "Oneplus": ["Oneplus"], 
    "Microsoft": ["Microsoft"],                      
    "Huawei": ["Huawei"],                        
    "Sony": ["Sony"], 
    "Lg": ["Lg"], 
    "Panasonic": ["Panasonic"], 
    "Plum": ["Plum"], 
    "Yu": ["Yu"], 
    "Verykool": ["Verykool"], 
    "Blackberry": ["Blackberry"], 
    "Alcatel": ["Alcatel"],                      
    "Apple": ["Iphone"], 
    "Iphone": ["Iphone"],            
    "Htc": ["Htc"], 
    "Acer": ["Acer"], 
    "Google": ["Google"] 
}
```

Y luego se crea una función que escoge la opción de acuerdo a las reglas que se establecio y aplicarlas usando `map`.

```
def mapper(val):
    for key, values in d.items():
        if any(value in val for value in values):
            return key
    return 'Otros'

df['brand'] = df.title.map(mapper)
```